# DB Compound indexing best practices Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-schema, database

How costly is it to index some fields in MongoDB,

I have a table where i want uniqueness combining two fields, Every where i search they suggested compound index with unique set to true.  But what i was doing is " Appending both field1_field2 and making it a key, so that field2 will be always unique for field1.(and add Application logic) As i thought indexing is costly.

And also as MongoDB documentation advices us not to use Custom Object ID like auto incrementing number, I end up giving big numbers to Models like Classes, Students etc, (where i could have used easily used 1,2,3 in sql lite), I didn't think to add a new field for numbering and index that field for querying.

What are the best practices advice for production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of using compound indexes vs your own indexed field system is that compound indexes allows sorting quicker than regular indexed fields. It also lowers the size of every documents.

In your case, if you want to get the documents sorted with values in `field1` ascending and in `field2` descending, it is better to use a compound index. If you only want to get the documents that have some specific value contained in `field1_field2`, it does not really matter if you use compound indexes or a regular indexed field.

However, if you already have `field1` and `field2` in seperate fields in the documents, and you also have a field containing `field1_field2`, it could be better to use a compound index on `field1` and `field2`, and simply delete the field containing `field1_field2`. This could lower the size of every document and ultimately reduce the size of your database.

Regarding the cost of the indexing, you almost have to index `field1_field2` if you want to go down that route anyways. Queries based on unindexed fields in MongoDB are *really* slow. And it does not take much more time adding a document to a database when the document has an indexed field (we're talking 1 millisecond or so). Note that adding an index on many existing documents can take a few minutes. This is why you usually plan the indexing strategy before adding any documents.

TL;DR:

If you have limited disk space or need to sort the results, go with a compound index and delete `field1_field2`. Otherwise, use `field1_field2`, but it has to be indexed!

Comment: My requirements is just to avoid duplicate key, field1 is say school id and field2 is student roll number, No school should have duplicate roll number, and for query i thought to pass the ObjectId of my Document to all my clients, so that whenever they request they will have the ObjectID, but doing so, i have to always send both "roll_number field and Object Id" in my every request to Server. 
Does indexing the field is more better approach in production than adding extra string in every request

Comment: I am not sure to fully understand your comment, but here's my answer:

Generally, you don't want to use custom ObjectIDs. Eventually, you might realize that your data model is not correct and need to change it. If you used a custom ObjectID, you might need to change it to make it fit with your new data model. The regular ObjectID is datamodel-agnostic, making it a good candidate no matter what the document contains. The regular ObjectID also contains [many useful informations](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

Comment: You mentioned that your primary concern is to avoid key duplication. Following this, I would avoid having an indexed field containing  `SchoolID_StudentRollNumber`, since it is a duplication of the fields `SchoolID` and `StudentRollNumber`. I would simply have the two fields seperated, but with a compound index. Those two fields would still be different than the `ObjectID field`, which would be a regular ObjectID. Then, when you want to query your server, you would send the `SchoolID` and `StudentRollNumber` to all your clients. Your clients would then query using both fields.